# Get rid of the thing at the top of the main.xml layout

Tags: android

Does anybody know how to get rid of the bar at the top of the main.xml layout that says the name of your application? I want to get rid of it, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Android Manifest.xml file where you added the Activity set the theme to Theme.NoTitleBar like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.onsource.activity.MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: Yea, I shouldn't have asked this lol. I found it right after I asked the question. Thanks anyways!

Comment: he wants to hide the application name from the xml....

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about Title bar? If so you can use the below code in your activity `onCreate`function to remove the title bar.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

make sure you call it before `setContentView()`.